# Systemd Service that is executed once after KDE Plasma desktop is loaded

Tags: systemd, kde, plasma

I created a systemd service that executes a script that changes the system color and the Wallpapers. I want the script to take effect after login and every 10min.

Principally it works, but the first execution gets lost. The script is called (i see it in the log files) but does not take effect when its called on boot. When it is executed the second time the changes are applied. My guess is that this is because the desktop session is loaded at the same time.

As a workaround i wait 2min for the first execution. But i would love to have it right after login. What is the correct keyword to wait on the desktop session?

/etc/systemd/user/kde_color_switch.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for color switch script
After=graphical.target xdg-user-dirs-update    #tried this ones 
Requires=graphical.target                      #what is the kde desktop loaded argument?

[Timer]
OnBootSec=0min
OnUnitActiveSec=10min

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

/etc/systemd/user/kde_color_switch.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Switches the kde color by time between light and dark

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/my_scripts/kde_auto_color_switch.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

part of /my_scripts/kde_auto_color_switch.sh:

```
if [ $(plasma-apply-colorscheme -l | grep "current color scheme" | grep Dracula | wc -l) -eq 1 ]
    then #if dark then switch light
        plasma-apply-colorscheme BreezeLight   #this line fails the first time

        sed -i "s/$imgNight/$imgDay/g" $kdeconfigdir/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
        konsole -e kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell --windowclass plasmashell --window Desktop >>/dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

As asked above I want to wait with the first execution until plasma desktop is fully up. I hope that then **plasma-apply-colorscheme BreezeLight** will take effekt.